# What kind of power sockets do Jet Airways' Boeing 777s have?

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items, power, jet-airways, boeing

A set of upcoming flights I have with [Jet Airways is on their Boeing 777-300ER planes](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Jet_Airways/Jet_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER.php) which offer shared power sockets in economy class. (Yay!) But what sort of power sockets would these be? Jet Airways' own site has no information on this either.

Comment: most, if not all, travel accessories come with universal adapters accepting an input voltage range from 110 to 240V. so hopefully you should be fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Jet_Airways/Jet_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER.php) it's [110VAC](http://www.seatguru.com/articles/in-seat_laptop_power.php):

> In seats equipped with AC Power, all you'll need is the standard wall power brick that came with your laptop or other electrical device. The power on the plane is typically 110V AC and features a semi-universal receptacle that accepts the following types of plugs:
>   US non-polarized 2-blade plug (both blades are the same size)
>   US polarized 2-blade plug (one blade is bigger than the other)
>   US non-polarized 2-blade plug with Ground (aka three-prong)
>   European standard 2-cylindrical prong plug (two round prongs)

Also found a [discusson on the subject on flyertalk.com](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/archive/t-647647.html).

Comment: I wanted to know which of the two between the US and European plugs. I'm not familiar enough with American plugs - does the polarised blade one need a special kind of plug adapter?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee No.  The polarized blade means that there is no separate ground i.e. 3rd prong.  If you have a European plug and universal power supply which most laptops are all you need is an adapter from EU to US like this: http://www.amazon.com/Europe-Adapter-convert-round-prongs/dp/B002TZBW74/ref=pd_bxgy_hi_img_b

Comment: Ah I think I get now what they meant by one blade longer than the other, I think I've seen those. Not a bother then whatever I end up with!

Comment: It's not longer it's wider: http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.trimark.com.hk/showroom/pic/product567_0.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.mahalo.com/answers/mathmos-lava-lamp-usa-adapter-i-bought-a-mathmos-lava-lamp-from-the-u-k-and-had-it-shipped-to-me-in-the-u-s&h=768&w=1024&sz=40&tbnid=EhubDL4HUdNnwM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=120&zoom=1&docid=BXjyyE_jUQnoWM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qfl1T52IB4ru0gHv_JzODQ&ved=0CEkQ9QEwAw&dur=929